# Publicar mensaje en página con imagen y/o video

Tags: php, facebook-api

Soy un novato en la programación para Facebook. 
Publico en una página de Facebook mediante el SDK de php con la versión 2.6 de la API. Consigo publicar un mensaje con texto pero me gustaría poder añadir imágenes y/o videos en la propia publicación pero no doy con la forma de hacerlo.

El tipo de código que estoy utilizando es (resumido) este

```
$linkData = [
   'message' => 'xxxx',
   'link' => 'xxxxx',
   'description' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
];
$response = $fb->post('/PAGE_ID/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
```

Por lo poco que he encontrado por ahí al respecto creo que debería de utilizarse *child_attachments* para poder añadir al mensaje las imágenes y videos pero no encuentro ningún ejemplo y la documentación de Facebook tampoco proporciona ninguno. 
 He probado con *sendBatchRequest* y funciona pero cada foto y cada video se añade en un mensaje independiente y lo que quiero es conseguir que un usuario postee un texto y si envia fotos y/o videos, se añadan al mismo mensaje, no cada uno en un mensaje.

¿Alguien tiene algún ejemplo de código que me pudiera facilitar?
Un saludo y muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que parece que nadie sabe (o quiere explicar) como hacerlo :-0 así que voy a poner lo que he conseguido hacer por el momento, por si le puede servir a alguien. He conseguido publicar en el mismo post, un texto con fotos y/o videos pero con particularidades. Me explico:

- La publicación se hace en forma de carrusel
- Como mínimo se deben añadir dos imágenes o videos porque si no, no funciona, al ser un carrusel

El código que he utilizado es:

```
$linkData = array(
 'message' => $mensaje,
    'child_attachments' => '[
    {"name":"Foto 1","link":"http://xxxxxxxx/xxx/foto.jpg","caption":"Caption Foto 1","description":"Descripción foto 1","picture":"http://xxxxxxxx/xxx/foto1.jpg"},
    {"name":"Video 1","link":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?xxxxxxx/","caption":"Caption Video 1","description":"Descripción Video 1","picture":"https://xxxxxxxxx"}
    ]',
);
```

En realidad no es esto lo que estaba buscando. **Lo que busco es publicar un mensaje simplemente con una o varias fotos y/o videos** y no un carrusel de fotos que, como mínimo, tenga que tener dos fotos para que funcione.
De verdad, ¿nadie sabe como hacerlo? Me resulta muy difícil de creer, no creo que sea tan complicado de hacer.
Un saludo